# laravel relation issue in many to many case

Tags: laravel, relation

i have three table in mysql:
1-users
[table of users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1SHa.jpg)
2-projects
[table of project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZ7Mn.jpg)
3-project_user

## there is id and project_id and user_id for relation

there is two model : user and project
the relation between these table are belongsToMany
when a project create maybe one project define for two person
NOW how can i show the project of each person?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you properly defined your relationships, do

```
$users = User::with('projects')->get();

//show each user projects
foreach($users as $user) {
    echo $user->projects;
}

//Getting project users 
$projects = Project::with('users')->get();
```

This will give you projects list, in each list you can see which user has access or not.

**Updates**

Taking project with specified user_id

```
$projects = Project::with(['users' => function ($query) use ($user_id) {
    $query->where('user_id', '=', $user_id);
}])->get();
```

**New code**
Or try to to get the user

```
$user = User::with('projects')->where('id', $user_id)->first();
```

Or via projects, constraining by user_id

```
$projects = Project::with('users')->whereHas('users', function ($query) use ($user_id) {
    $query->where($user_id);
})->get();
```

Comment: look there is three table with two model, one model for users and another for projects and there isnt any mode for project_user table. when i define a project for two users i need to show that project just to that two user not otheres. and this rule is on project_user table . how can i select it when there is nt any model? and this three table are relational

Comment: Check my update. You can get a user and see all their projects. Or get a project, and see all the users who have access to it.

Comment: Sorry I check your Update But There Is A Problem : You  Know I Need To Get Project With Specific user_id In A project_user Table.Now I Have That user_id But In Your Query How I Should Use It?

Comment: There is a problem i have user_id 2 and i define two project for him but when i use your query show all project to user_id 2!!!

Comment: how can i send the picture of my tables for you because i confuse i try to solve it but until now i cant do it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your question, you want to query `Project` as per `user_id`. Here is how you do it.

```
 Project::with('users')->whereHas('users', function ($query) use ($user_id_array) {
        $query->whereIn('id',$user_id_array);
    })->get();
```

This will give you projects whose `user_id` are from `$user_id_array`. Let me know if you need any further help.

Comment: I send User Id in JSon : for example i have to project for user id 2.now the error is Undefined variable: user_id_array?

Comment: I send User Id in JSon : for example i have to project for user id 2.now the error is Missing argument 2 for Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::whereIn(), called in ...

Answer (score 0):

the way i solve it:

```
//save user_id
$user_id = $request->id;
//select in project_user where user_id = $user_id
$project_user = DB::table('project_user')->where('user_id', '=', $user_id)->get();
//create an empty array
$p_id = array();
//fill empty array with project_id
foreach($project_user as $pro) {
$p_id[] =  $pro->project_id;
}
//select code and id in project table where id = one of that [$p_id] array
$data = Project::select('code','id')->whereIn('id', $p_id)->get();
//return your data in json
return response()->json($data);
```